# Data from Excel in .json

Tags: json, combobox, transform, xlsx

As a non-programmer, after some searching on the internet I have not found a solution to the following challenge.

Initial state: I have an Excel file which has the same structure as the attached image "Raw data", only with 5000+ rows.

Target state: I want a .json that has the structure like

```
{
    "Berlin": {
        "1-Personen-Haushalt": {
            "1 Zimmer": [
                "20 qm",
                "30 qm",
                "40 qm",
                "50 qm",
                "60 qm",
                "70 qm"
            ],
            "2 Zimmer": [
                "20 qm",
                "30 qm",
                "40 qm",
                "50 qm",
                "60 qm",
                "70 qm"
            ]
        },
```

Etc.

It should serve as a basis for combo boxes. The selection of the first should define the selection options of the second. The selection of the second should define the selection options of the third. Etc.

It is not as trivial as in my example, so there is not always "20 qm" or "2 Zimmer". I mean real patterns.

I have already formatted the data a little, in the hope that it would then be easier. See "Formatted data"

I have already tried to insert the formatted data into a .json in Visual Studio Code, but did not get the desired result.

Maybe you have an idea how to approach this :)

[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjw5l.png)
[Formatted Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfxcG.png)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you first convert the xlsx file to csv, then parse it with papaparse and then use some sort of function to get what you want.

Papaparse section:

```
let data;
const csv = fs.readFileSync('example.csv', 'utf8');

Papa.parse(csv, {
  complete: (results) => {
    results.data.pop();
    data = results.data;
  }
});
```

formatter to get your desired json file:

```
function formatter(data) {
  let result = {};
  data.forEach((item) => {
    let [city, person, room, size] = item;
    if (!result[city]) {
      result[city] = {};
    }
    if (!result[city][person]) {
      result[city][person] = {};
    }
    if (!result[city][person][room]) {
      result[city][person][room] = [];
    }
    result[city][person][room].push(size);
  });
  return result;
}
```

and you can save result as json:

```
let result = formatter(data);
fs.writeFileSync('result.json', JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```